# Unable to Cast Object Anonymous Generic List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, casting

If you have any idea how I would enumerate the object list please let me know. Here is how it is created. I’ve been unable to cast it to a List, IList, Enumerable, IEnumerable for some reason. I’m guessing it’s because of how it was created (by a third party). Just seeing if anyone has any ideas.

The error is as follows:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SugarRest.Model.AMP_Product_Line]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SugarRest.Model.AMP_Product_Line]'.
```

The object is created as follows:

```
private static AMP_Contract CreateCrmContract(ContractDetailViewModel model, int bookmanContractNumber, int renewedFromContractNumber)
        {
            List<AMP_Product_Line> productLines = CreateProductLinesPrint(model, bookmanContractNumber);

            //Contract
            AMP_Contract ampContract = new AMP_Contract();

            ...

            ampContract.amp_amp_contracts_amp_amp_product_lines = new { productLines };

            return ampContract;
        }

public class AMP_Contract
    {              
        ...
        public object amp_amp_contracts_amp_amp_product_lines { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

The object that I am trying to access/enumerate is as follows:

[image: vc]

[image]

I also tried this, however, the object in question is not enumerable as it it an object.

[image]

Comment: Whoever designed this object model is likely *actively trying to prevent you from doing this*.  Why they would do that, you'll have to ask them, but they are deliberately creating an "unspeakable" type. Using anonymous types like this is a bad practice in C#; you should probably follow up with the author of the code to find out why they are concealing their details in this way; odds are good that you are not supposed to be accessing that information; if accessing it was by design, they would have made it easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: whoever wrote this code is actively attempting to stop you from accessing that collection. You should think very hard about whether it is the right thing to try to defeat their attempt; they probably are hiding that for a reason.

The easiest way to do that is to use dynamic to read the value out of the anonymous type. You can then do a dynamic conversion to the sequence type you need:

```
var contract = CreateCrmContract(...whatever...);
dynamic d = contract.amp_amp_contracts_amp_amp_product_lines;
IEnumerable<AMP_Product_Line> lines = d.productLines;
```

And now we are back in the statically typed world:

```
foreach (AMP_Product_Line line in lines)
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

you must write a method for this

```
public static object ToNonAnonymousList<T>(this List<T> list, Type t)
{

   //define system Type representing List of objects of T type:
   var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);

   //create an object instance of defined type:
   var l = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

   //get method Add from from the list:
   MethodInfo addMethod = l.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

   //loop through the calling list:
   foreach (T item in list)
   {

      //convert each object of the list into T object 
      //by calling extension ToType<T>()
      //Add this object to newly created list:
      addMethod.Invoke(l, new object[] { item.ToType(t) });
   }

   //return List of T objects:
   return l;
}
```

use of

```
var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
```

review for example

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38635/Converting-anonymous-types-to-any-type

Comment: This is a very over-complicated way to solve this problem. See my answer for a much shorter and more elegant solution.